# Возможный способ организации документации

Tags: документация

Здравствуйте.

Возникла необходимость отслеживания версий документации.

Рассмотрим на примере Read the Docs.

Пользователь заходит на сайт с документацией:

и ему выводится что-то по типу такого, только в левом части окна, выводятся версии документации v.1.0, v.1.2. и пользователь может просмотреть каждую версию документации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли мысли по этому поводу? Может посоветуете что из готовых решений?

Может есть готовые рецепты для Read the Docs, чтобы так сделать?

Comment: sphinx + sphinx-rtd-theme

Comment: Про версии: [How do I have multiple versions of my doc with sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849284/how-do-i-have-multiple-versions-of-my-doc-with-sphinx)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за информацию.) Сейчас пробнем.

Comment: @andreymal сделай как ответ. Рейтинг точно поставлю.

Comment: О, коллега-единомышленник! Я как раз работаю с документацией, причем Sphinx и RTD Theme, только мы хостимся не на RTD, а сами.

Comment: Заходите в чатик: https://telegram.me/docsascode

Comment: Я постараюсь написать развернутый ответ на этой неделе.

Comment: @andreymal а вы тоже работаете со Sphinx?

Comment: @NickVolynkin совсем немного

Comment: @andreymal тогда и вас приглашаю в чатик: https://telegram.me/docsascode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось легче. 
Можно добиться, чтобы было по версиям, главное, чтобы в вашем репозитории были коммиты с метками(без разницы какие). 
Вы делаете коммит и ReadTheDocs автоматически подтягивает вашу метку как отдельную версию. После чего можно выбирать что и какую версию отображать.

Comment: То есть ReadTheDocs был не просто примером, а вопрос был целиком именно про него? Тогда все мои старые комментарии не имеют значения) Я думал, что вопрос про документацию вообще

Comment: @andreymal не. Тогда и правда рассматривались альтернативы по нужным параметром. Но потом нашли как добиться нужного результата. Так что не зря вы писали, может кому и поможет. )